# hadoop/bin/hadoop doesn't have the example jar

Tags: hadoop

I installed hadoop 2.2.0 and try to run sample wordcount program. For that, first I imported data in to hdfs using:

```
bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/prassanna/Desktop/input /input
```

After that, I tried to run word count jar file using:

```
root@prassanna-Studio-1558:/usr/local/hadoop# bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount /input -output
```

but it showed: `Not a valid JAR: /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop*examples*.jar`

I checked in `usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop` directory and there is no hadoop example jar.

Comment: Is the sample that you found for hadoop 2.2.0, or a previous version? What tutorial did you follow?

Comment: Are you sure about the JAR file name?

Answer (score 3):

The `Jar` file you are looking for is in this directory:

```
hadoop_root/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar
```

and should be run with a command like this:

```
$ yarn jar hadoop_root/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /input /output
```

Comment: i had found the hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar in the following dir usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce but while i tried to run root@prassanna-Studio-1558:/usr/local/hadoop# bin/yarn  jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreducehadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /input /output but got the following error Not a valid JAR: /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreducehadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar,please help to run this

Comment: you clearly are missing a `/`! you should use it this way: `bin/yarn jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /input /output`

Comment: hi SAM , i used like this root@Prassanna:usr/local/hadoop:bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /input /output and it worked fine . i browsed and checked in UI also it showed all the files with word count

Comment: @user2631600 I am happy to know that. If this is the answer to your question, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop example jar is no more present here.

```
usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop
```

From hadoop version 2.x, as SAM has rightly indicated in his answer, the jar you are looking for is

```
$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar
```

You can run it like,

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /input /output
```

Make sure `/input` folder has an input file to be counted in the hdfs. Also note that `/output` should *not* exist. This is for the hadoop framework to create.

Also please refer to this document to use the Hadoop2.2.0 Shell Commands. It is always a good practice to not use the deprecated version.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Answer (score 1):

In my hadoop, I am working in 2.4.1 so the command is

hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.1.jar wordcount /input /output

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the WordCount.java and then JAR it as follows below. I had to dig around for the lib paths, but in the end I was able to use this to compile the examples Class

```
[apesa@localhost ~]$ javac -classpath $HADOOP_HOME/apesa/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/apesa/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:$HADOOP_HOME/apesa/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

Then JAR it as follows

```
[apesa@localhost ~]$ jar -cvf wordcount.jar -C wordcount_classes/ .
```

I have not run this in a while but you may have to verify the lib files are in the same place if you get an error