# Exception during wordcount in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, word-count

I have installed Hadoop successfully and now I want to run `Wordcount.jar`. As shown below, my source address is `/user/amir/dft/pg5000.txt` and destination address to save results is `/user/amir/dft/output.txt`.

I have downloaded the `.jar` file from [this url](http://salsahpc.indiana.edu/tutorial/hadoopwc1.html).
Now I'm facing this error message when I run the below command. I followed the instructions found at [this url](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) and now my problem is on "Run the MapReduce job" step. How can I overcome it?

```
amir@amir-Aspire-5820TG:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/wordcount.jar wordcount /user/amir/dft/pg5000.txt /user/amir/dft/output.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: wordcount
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
amir@amir-Aspire-5820TG:/usr/local/hadoop$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to download a new `.jar` file. A wordcount jar is already there in the examples of hadoop. Just use the command:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount  /user/amir/dft /user/amir/dft-output
```

The input and output paths should be directories on HDFS, not files. This will run the wordcount program on all the files that are uploaded on HDFS under the `/user/amir/dft/` path, (including your `pg5000.txt` file).

**EDIT**: If you want to run this specific jar that you have downloaded, though, follow [@samthebest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25381463/2516301) (keeping in mind that the input&output paths are directories).

**EDIT2**: Following the comments of this answer, it seems that the hadoop version used is newer than the one described in the tutorial. So the `.jar` for the wordcount program is located at the path `hadoop_root/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar`, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351685/error-in-wordcount-example-in-hadoop2-2-0).

Comment: thanks for response. I have executed a command but it produce below error:amir@amir-Aspire-5820TG:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount  /user/amir/dft /user/amir/dft-outpu
Not a valid JAR: /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop*examples*.jar

Comment: Then perhaps you have installed a newer hadoop version (2.x) than the one of this tutorial. If that's the case, try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351685/error-in-wordcount-example-in-hadoop2-2-0. It says that the `.jar` should be found in this path: `hadoop_root/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar`

Comment: yes, i have hadoop ver 2.4.1 and i run map-reduce with this command:yarn jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.1.jar wordcount /user/amir/dft /user/amir/dft
now, how i can see the output?and how i can fuond that it executed sucessfully?

Comment: You can see the output by viewing the contents of `/user/amir/dft-output`. Note that the input path should be different than the output path, otherwise, you will overwrite the input files. See the shell commands of hdfs by typing: `bin/hdfs dfs -help`. If this was a correct answer to your original post, then please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: yeah this link was useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351685/error-in-wordcount-example-in-hadoop2-2-0

Answer (score 1):

It means u have a typo or somthing wrong with the main class your specifying. Do u mean `org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount` instead of `wordcount`.